# Why does resultar have le/les before it?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, verbos, pronombres

What is the purpose of *le/les* in the following sentences:

> Juan estaba intentando sentarse. Le resultaba difícil respirar.

> Les resultaba difícil creerlo.

The verb *gustar* functions with a *le/les* before it. Does *resultar* work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos **el pronombre** "*le*" y "*les*" (singular y plural, respectivamente) desempeñan la función de complemento indirecto.

- Juan estaba intentando sentarse. Le resultó difícil respirar. ¿A quien **le** resulto difícil respirar? A él, a Juan.
- (A ellos) Les resultó difícil creerlo. ¿A quien **les** resulto difícil creerlo? A ellos.

En este caso el verbo "*gustar*" se utiliza igual.

**P.D.** Como simple curiosidad en el S. XVIII era normal expresar "**le**" o "**les**" conjuntamente detrás del verbo, así por ejemplo se decía; "Resulto**le** difícil respirar" o "Gusto**le** mucho la comida".
Hoy en día, si bien se puede decir y no es incorrecto, posee un matiz arcaizante. En el español actual el pronombre se antepone a las formas conjugadas del verbo, pero antiguamente era común verlo también de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not include any pronoun there the reader would ask themselves who was having difficulty breathing. Watching Juan trying to sit down might have made me hold my breath *Me resultaba difícil respirar*. We do not have the same sort of construction in English as we would say something like He found it difficult to breathe. In that sense it is similar to the way to use *gustar*.